# Does Midorima's shooting ability have a name?

Tags: kuroko-no-basket

- Akashi → Emperor Eye
- Kise → Perfect Copy
- Aomine → Formless Shot (among others)
- Murasakibara → Thor's Hammer
- Midorima → ???

Does Midorima's ability to shoot 3-pointers from anywhere on the court have a super-cool name like the special techniques of the rest of the Generation of Miracles?

There's a few frames in the last OP of season 3 that say "Sky Direct 3P Shoot" in green text, which I suppose sounds kind of like a description of Midorima's technique, but I don't recall having heard that in the anime. (It's also the only move name in that OP I can't match up to a player, for what it's worth.)

Comment: Emperor Eye is not a shooting ability. It's an eye ability, like Sharingan and Byakugan is. Same with Kise's Perfect Copy.

Comment: I wasn't making a distinction between "shooting abilities" and "other abilities". I was just bucketing all the various basketball superpowers together as just "abilities".

Comment: Akashi's signature move is Ankle Break. Midorima's signature shot as answered is High Projectile three.

Answer (score 3):

Well, in the manga, his skill is also hardly mentioned, and when he does it, he is "shooting" and mostly translated as "Midorima's super long 3-pointer/shooting" or some variation. There wasn't a special name for it.

The wikia lists it as:

> Talent:
> High Projectile Three
> Perfect Accuracy
>  Unlimited Range

Source: http://kurokonobasuke.wikia.com/wiki/Shintar%C5%8D_Midorima

So I guess there really isn't a "special" name for his move. Just a super long 3 pointer.